# Magento2 Rest API Order Flow

Tags: api, rest-api, payment-gateway, magento2.1.0

I am making REST API calls to magento website for order placement. Below is the sequence of my calls.

1. Create a cart  `rest/V1/guest-carts/`
2. Get the cart `rest/V1/guest-carts/bae0af147b83f1561f66cc4e3c97916e`
3. Add products to cart `rest/V1/guest-carts/24/items`
4. Add billing information, set payment method and place order `rest/V1/guest-carts/24/payment-information`

In this sequence the order is getting the placed with order status "pending". I am wondering how the payment is captured through api if any payment gateway(Ex. PayPal) is involved to process payment and generate invoice.

Is there any api missing in the above flow for capturing payments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have used a fresh installation for the following using Magento2 CE 2.2.0-dev, and left the default "Luma" theme as well.

Concerning external payment methods (gateways) such as [MiGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastercard_Internet_Gateway_Service), [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/), [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com), and others, Magento supports these gateways out of the box but provides NO APIs for them that you can use along with other "Checkout" APIs.

So, if you are planning to build a checkout app/page using Magento's APIs, you will need to manually integrate with these services using their SDK/API, fortunately, you can learn a lot by checking how Magento integrates with these services in the built-in integrations.

To understand this, i had to configure Braintree since it is the easiest:

1. Create sandbox account at https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox
2. Access Magento Admin Area.
3. Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Braintree > Configure.
4. Make sure "Environment" is "Sandbox", and enter "Merchant ID", "Public Key", and "Private Key".
5. Save Config.
6. You may need to reindex and/or refresh cache.

Upon adding a product to the cart and proceeding to checkout, in the last step, choose the Braintree payment method, then after clicking the "Place Order" button, you will notice the following AJAX requests:

1. 2 requests to Braintree API to validate the card, perform the transaction, and responds with transaction status.
2. A request to Magento's API `guest-carts/cartId/payment-information` with the usual body as explained in Magento's API documentation.

After that the process continues as expected with redirection to success page when the last request responds in JSON containing the order `entity_id`

[image]

This confirms that calls to external services -Braintree in our example- is performed by the checkout page NOT by Magento internally, so we will need to do the same if we are to develop our own checkout page/app.

As for controlling the order status, i dug deeper and found out that using payment methods like MiGS, Braintree, or PayPal, resulted in an order with status `processing` instead of the usual `pending`, i suspected that this is either a payment-method configuration or an observer, but it appeared to be a configuration, here are more details.

Class: Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment

Method: Place()

There is a conditional that checks if `Initialization` is required for the method `if ($methodInstance->isInitializeNeeded())`, if that's the case, a method `initialize()` is executed which you define, and allows you to specify both `state` and `status`.

Comment: can you share the payload for the payment-information api

Comment: {"cartId":"a98697cba964d6ba0d3b64d78a31df33","billingAddress":{"countryId":"EG","regionId":null,"region":"","street":["street",""],"company":"my company","telephone":"12346987","postcode":"12345","city":"city","firstname":"f name","lastname":"l name","saveInAddressBook":null},"paymentMethod":{"method":"braintree","additional_data":{"payment_method_nonce":"ef27df81-7c29-4a74-9049-15de33f1f49f"}},"email":"email@example.com"}

Comment: Thanks for the payload. I am wondering, how to generate "payment_method_nonce".

Comment: Don't really know but i think by inspecting requests back and forth that nonce can be easily discovered, if it really functions as a nonce.

Comment: Braintree seems easy to integrate throught REST API. But how to integrate the external redirection payment gateway such as Papal or Ingenico ?